# UWP Combobox items scrolls to mid for no reason

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, combobox, scrollviewer

I noticed that in a combobox which has some itemsource attached to it, when there is no selected item it tends to scroll to middle of the item instead of starting at the top (first item) and when an item is selected it does sometime scroll to the selected item.

So I want to scroll to first item when no item is selected. For that I tried following fixes.

### Code

```
    private void ComboBoxKeyboardSelectionBehavior_DropDownOpened(object sender, object e)
    {
        var comboBox = (ComboBox) sender;
        if(comboBox.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            //var scrollviewer = comboBox.GetScrollViewer();
            //scrollviewer.ChangeView(0, 0, null);
            //var allItems = comboBox.Items.ToList();
            //var cccc = comboBox.Items.Count;
            //var firstItem = allItems.First();
            var ci = comboBox.ContainerFromIndex(0) as ComboBoxItem;
            if (ci != null)
            {
                ci.StartBringIntoView();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var ci = comboBox.ContainerFromIndex(comboBox.SelectedIndex) as ComboBoxItem;
            if (ci != null)
            {
                ci.StartBringIntoView();
            }
        }
    }
```

**WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.Extensions** gave me the option to get scrollviewer and then try the **ChangeView** method but that isn't working. I got the First item from the list successfully and used the **ContainerFromItem** method but it returned me null. So I also tried **ContainerFromIndex** method and provided index as **0** because that is supposed to be the first item, but that aint working either.

In case of selected item (else statement) it is working fine with `ContainerFromIndex(comboBox.SelectedIndex)` but just to test when I tried it with **ContainerFromItem** it returned null.

Just FYI, this event is in an attached behavior to the combobox style but that shouldn't matter because behavor works flawlessly for selected item scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scroll to the first item when there is no selected item, you need to change the behavior of the `DropDown` of a `ComboBox` instead of `ScrollViewer` of a `ComboBox`.

The `DropDown` of a `ComboBox` is acutally a `Popup`, and the position where to show the `Popup` is defined in the code behind, and we can’t access to it. One workaround is finding the `Popup` and relocate it when it is opened, but using this method we need to calculate the `VerticalOffset` property each time when it is opened, and there are quite many scenarios for different value of `VerticalOffset`.

Therefore, we suggest you custom a control whose behavior like a `ComboBox` and position to the first item when no item is selected. For example:

Create a `UserControl`:

```
<Button x:Name="rootButton" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2" Click="Button_Click" MinWidth="80" Background="Transparent" Padding="0">
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
      Width="{Binding ElementName=rootButton, Path=ActualWidth}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="32" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind selectedItem, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <FontIcon Grid.Column="1" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE0E5;" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
           Margin="0,10,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
<FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
    <MenuFlyout Placement="Bottom" x:Name="menuFlyout">
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item 1" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click" />
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item 2" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click" />
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item 3" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click" />
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item 4" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click" />
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item 5" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click" />
    </MenuFlyout>
</FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
```

And the code behind in this UserControl:

```
public sealed partial class CustomComboBox : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public CustomComboBox()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        selectedItem = "";
    }

    private string _selectedItem;

    public string selectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }

        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("selectedItem"));
           }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void MenuFlyoutItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = sender as MenuFlyoutItem;
        selectedItem = item.Text;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(sender as Button);
    }
}
```

You can use the `CustomComboBox` in other page like this:

```
<local:CustomComboBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

By defalult this `CustomComboBox` will show its `DropDown` list under it.

In addition, you can also consider using other control such as a `ListBox` to directly replace the `ComboBox` to avoid the situation.

**Update:**

Currently, the `ComboBox` control does not provide related APIs for setting the starting position of `DropDown` in a `Style`, but we have a workaround to get the `ScrollViewer` inside the `DropDown`,and then call the `ChangeView` method to change the position. For example:

1. Define a custom combo box inherited from `ComboBox` class to get the `ScrollViewer`:

```cs
    public class TestComboBox : ComboBox
    {
        public ScrollViewer InternalScrollViewer;
        protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            InternalScrollViewer = GetTemplateChild("ScrollViewer") as ScrollViewer;
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
        }
    }
```

2. Call the `ChangeView` method to change the position after items are initialized by using `Task.Delay()` in the `ComboBoxKeyboardSelectionBehavior_DropDownOpened` event handler:

```cs
    await Task.Delay(50);
    comboBox.InternalScrollViewer.ChangeView(0, 0, 1);
```

Note, use `TestComboBox` instead of `ComboBox` in **XAML**.

Comment: Has your problem been solved? If it is not solved, please feel free to contact us.

Comment: I was hoping to find a solution within the style and behaviors so that we dnt need to make a custom control as we have bulk of comboboxes and making a custom control probably not the best idea for our scenario.

Comment: we already have a style for combobox where we r doing lot of custom stuff in xaml as well as some behaviors attached to it.

Comment: I update the answer, you could check if the new workaround can solve your problem.